# Generating teams for a game in order to satisfy a certain rule/property

Tags: probability

How would I go about solving the probability question below?

Rick is planning a game with his buddies Abby, Bette, Charles, David, Edward, Frances, Gwen, Harry, Ian, and Jay. This game will be played by forming teams of two people. To keep things interesting, Rick has recommended that none of the teams comprise of best friends, which means that no participant can pair up with his or her closest buddy. For the sake of simplicity, let us refer to this rule as "M". Assume Abby and Harry are best friends, Bette and David are best friends, Charles and Edward are best friends, and Frances and Gwen are best friends, and Ian is best friends with Jay. Rick has proposed the following process, dubbed "Z," to build teams: On separate cards, he has scribbled the names Abby, Bette, Charles, Frances, and Ian. He placed those five cards on a table in such a manner that no one would be able to read the names inscribed on them. Now, Harry, David, Edward, Gwen, and Jay will each choose one card (without replacing) and be matched with the person whose name is inscribed on that card.

What is the probability that the method "Z" will generate teams that follow the rule "M"?

What is the probability that the method "Z" will NOT generate teams that follow the rule "M"?

This is the way I thought it would be done:

[The Way I did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEfTS.png)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: So would the approach be similar to something like this?

There are 5! ways to arrange the 5 people on the cards.

There are 5!/2! ways to arrange the 5 people on the cards such that 2 best friends are together.

The probability that the method "Z" will generate teams that follow the rule "M" is 1 - (5!/2!)/5! = 1/2.

The probability that the method "Z" will NOT generate teams that follow the rule "M" is 1/2.

Comment: Look up [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Why downvoting/closing a question where there is work ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see work. "The Way I did it" just seems to guess 0.5 without any work shown.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Thanks for the information! I

Comment: @Joe I have added more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule $M$ means that none of the names in the same vertical line match

$A\,\,B\,\,C\,F\,I$
$H\,D\,E\,G\,J$

Now $H$ does have a probability of $\frac45$ of following rule $M,$

Suppose $H$ chooses $B$, $D$ does **not** have a probability of $\frac34$ of following rule $M$, in fact **any** of the $4$ choices left will follow rule $M !$

If rule $M$ is to be followed in toto,
the top line and bottom line must be fully [deranged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement%20is%20a%20permutation,is%20a%20permutation%20that%20has%20no%20fixed%20points.)

One of the formulas for a full derangement of a row of $n$ is $!n$ (subfactorial $n$) which is $44$ for $n=5$

Thus $P(M) = \dfrac{!5}{5!} = \dfrac{44}{120}=\dfrac{11}{30}$

and $P(M^C) = \dfrac{19}{30}$

Comment: Thank you for this clarification!

Comment: You're welcome !